# How to integrate $4\cos^2 (\theta) \sin^2 (\theta)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Should I change it into $4 \cos^2 (\theta) (1-\cos^2(\theta))$ or is there any possible way to use product rule?

Comment: Think of $\sin 2 \theta$.

Comment: You have been around for 5 months. Haven't you noticed yet that you are supposed to use MathJax in your questions?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use that $$4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)= (\sin(2x))^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int { 4\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } \sin ^{ 2 }{ x } dx } =\int { { \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( 2x \right) dx }  } } \\ \int { \frac { 1-\cos { \left( 4x \right)  }  }{ 2 }  } dx=\frac { x }{ 2 } -\frac { \sin { \left( 4x \right)  }  }{ 8 } +c $$

Answer (score 1):

TIP$_1$: $4\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta = (2\sin\theta\cos\theta)^2 = \sin^2\,2\theta$.

TIP$_2$: $\cos\,2\theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$, for all $\theta \in \Bbb R$.